# sphinx : nested include across nested directories

Tags: python-sphinx

Does sphinx allow nested includes ?

I have a hierarchy that looks like that:

```
~> root
   |_conf.py
   |_index.rst
   |_level1.rst
   |_level2
     |_level2.rst
     |_level3
       |_level3.rst
```

Files look this way:

```
~> more conf.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('level1'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('level1/level2'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('level1/level2/level3'))
project = 'PM'
copyright = '2020, PM'
author = 'PM'
extensions = [
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build']
```

Note: all sublevels are added in sys.path.

The index just adds level1.

```
~> more index.rst
Welcome to PM's documentation!
==============================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 6
   :caption: Contents:

   level1
```

And the rst files look like :

```
~> more level1.rst
level1
######

this is level1

.. include:: level2/level2.rst

~> more level2/level2.rst
level2
======

this is level2

.. include:: level3/level3.rst

~> more .\level2\level3\level3.rst
level3
------

this is level3
```

The compilation emits this warning :

```
~> make latexpdf
...
reading sources... [100%] level2/level3/level3
level2/level2.rst:6: WARNING: Problems with "include" directive path:
InputError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'level3/level3.rst'.
...
```

Table of content is OK down to level 2 :

```
1 level1
  1.1 level2
```

But level 3 is missing:

```
     1.1.1 level3
```

Level 3 is ignored.

Is there a way to get this to work ? This way or another ? Or any workaround ?
For instance is there a way to say "pwd is now level2" in level2.rst ?

**UPDATE**

Real life application looks more like:

```
~> root
   |_conf.py
   |_index.rst
   |_level1.rst
   |_level2
   | |_conf.py
   | |_index.rst
   | |_level2.rst
   | |_level3
   |   |_conf.py
   |   |_index.rst
   |   |_level3.rst
   |_level4
     |_conf.py
     |_index.rst
     |_level4.rst
     |_level3
       |_conf.py
       |_index.rst
       |_level3.rst
```

`level3` is actually a `git-submodule` that is cloned into both `level2` and `level4` but on **different** branches where the doc may **not** be the same.

Ideally, `level3` should generate his own doc. `level2` and `level4` should generate his own doc including the one of `level3`. `level1` should generate his own doc including the ones of both `level2` (which embed doc of `level3`) and `level4` (which embed doc of `level3`).

This is why all paths are relatives in my first simplified attempt.

I try to understand if this (ideal case) could be possible.

Comment: The problem is in this line `.. include:: level3/level3.rst` should be `.. include:: level2/level3/level3.rst`

Comment: To add to @bad_coder's comment, I prefer to use root-relative paths where the root is the location of your `conf.py`.

Comment: Note that `sys.path` is a list of strings that specify search paths for Python modules. It has nothing to do with the structure of nested `include` directives.

Comment: @bad_coder: I understand ``.. include:: level2/level3/level3.rst`` works.In real life, there is a ``level4`` at same level than ``level2``. ``level3`` is actually a ``git-submodule`` that is cloned into both ``level2`` and ``level4`` but on **different** branches where the doc may **not** be the same. I look ideally for a solution with only relative path if possible (not involving "upper information")

Comment: @StevePiercy: in real life, ideally, each ``levelX`` is an independant projet which has his own ``conf.py`` and ``index.rst``. I try to understand if I can reuse the doc of one (lower) level into the doc of another (upper) level. This is why all path are relatives in my attempt. ``level3`` should generate his own doc. ``level2`` should generate his own doc including the one of ``level3``. ``level1`` should generate his own doc including the ones of both ``level2`` and ``level3``. I try to understand if this is possible or not

Comment: Documentation generated from Sphinx uses a single `conf.py` from where it is invoked. See another recent question and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786355/sphinx-include-documents-from-a-package#comment114597610_64786355) about documenting nested projects.

Comment: @StevePiercy: thanks for the tip ! Didn't know about ``intersphinx`` : I will give it a try if I find an example (still looking for it). From what I have read, ``intersphinx`` allow from a given doc to reference something from another doc : this is not really what I had in mind at first (i.e. embedding doc into another one), but, it's worth looking at it

Comment: Yup, it should work. "Each target is the base URI of a foreign Sphinx documentation set and can be a *local path* or an HTTP URI." Most people do remote HTTP URIs, but I reckon you can do the same locally. Build each subproject, then in the parent project use intersphinx.

Comment: @StevePiercy : tried intersphinx but without success https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691569/is-it-possible-to-create-nested-pdf-documentation-with-sphinxintersphinx

Comment: @FGH the local path must be to the build directory `../projectA/_build `, not the source.

Comment: @StevePiercy: does not work either, check out updated answer

Comment: Where is your build directory for projectA relative to projectB?

Comment: In `conf.py` of projectB, I set `intersphinx_mapping = {'projA': (os.path.join('..', 'projectA', '_build'), None)}` which is the relative path that points at projectA. Main problem seems to be : there is no `objects.inv` file (in projectA)